# problem with apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I am using mysql with PHP. I have a problem with inserting the apostrophe value in database. However I use -

```
$newstring = str_replace("'","&apos;",$string);
```

OR

```
$newstring = str_replace("'","''",$string);
```

but how could I fetch the string as it is?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Could you clarify 'fetch the string as is'?

Comment: Possible Duplicates: [How do you encode an apostrophe so that it's searchable in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620783/how-do-you-encode-an-apostrophe-so-that-its-searchable-in-mysql); [PHP Apostrophe and query string.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951250/php-apostrophe-and-query-string)

Comment: @user820561: Next to the problem you have to actually store the string (I assume you want to store it unchanged) to the database, you're probably even facing a SQL injection. You can store the string unchanged into the database by making use of the `mysql_real_escape_string` function instead of using your self-cooked `str_replace`. That's for what it has been made for. And it helps to prevent sql injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to escape it, use `addslashes()` to sanitise it, or better yet, `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
mysql_real_escape_string($string)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggesation. I used it, but while inserting it into table it inserts value as -  abcd\'s  , so while fetching string comes as it is  abcd\'s. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @user: While fetching, use `stripslashes` function :)